# Creating interface fields to inject vs Objects?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

In the tutorial I'm doing it uses interfaces to inject things, for example it uses a **IHotDrink interface**, then creates a **Tea class** that implements **IHotDrink**. It then has a third class called **Restaurant** that has a **IHotDrink** field inside the class and initializes it in the constructor. It then goes on by injecting a **Tea Class** into the **Restaurant class's constructor (which takes a IHotDrink interface argument)**

So basically my question is: Does every field that is going to be injected need to be an interface?

Lets say I have a bunch of food items that all implement a **IHotFoods interface**, and a bunch of drinks that all implement the **IHotDrink Interface**, would it be okay If I have a **meal class** that doesn't implement anything and takes in a **IHotFood** interface and a **IHotDrink** Interface as arguments into its constructor (that will later be injected by different food/drinks classes ) **and then have a meal field in the restaurant class that I can inject with different meal objects?** Would this be okay? Or would I have to: **Make a meals interface, have meal implement meals, and have Restaurant have a meals interface field that I can inject meal into?**

I'm not asking whether every class should implement an interface, I'm asking whether they should always have **interface fields** to inject other classes into them that also implement the interface. (like in the example in the tutorial)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not necessary to always have interface fields to inject other classes into them that also implement the interface.
Interfaces just help you to inject different fields implementing the same interface.

Using the IHotDrink interface field in the Restaurant class gives you the flexibility to have Tea which implements IHotDrink as well as Coffee which too implements IHotDrink.

Regarding your "Meal" example, as you have already used IHotDrink and IHotFood in the Meal class, you can have any hot drink and hot food in the Meal class, hence you need not have to create a Meals interface and have meal implement meals.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not asking whether every class should implement an interface, I'm
>   asking whether they should always have interface fields to inject
>   other classes into them that also implement the interface.

You may try and you would see that you don't need to specify an interface to allow a class to be an injectable bean.
Defining an interface makes sense generally in two cases :

- as you have multiple implementations and don't want to do a restriction on the declared type.
- as you use bytecode generation at runtime to create dynamically the runtime class that will implement the wished interface (case for example for `org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository`).